# Triangle integral with vertices

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$I=\iint\limits_R \sin \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\, dA,$$ where $R$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$.
>
> Hint: use $u=\dfrac{x+y}{2},v=\dfrac{x-y}{2}$.

Can anyone help me with this question I am very lost. Please help
I know you can make the intergal $\sin(u)\cos(v)$, but then what to do?

Comment: Hint: Use the hint. What happens to the triangular integration region then?

Comment: it would become sin(u)cos(v) this is where i get lost.

Comment: Do you know what a change of coordinates is and how you can use them to simplify integrals? Does the word Jacobian mean anything to you?

Comment: No i do not get what you are saying. Hint?

Comment: Did you learn Jacobian in your class? or you missed it?

Comment: No i did not learn it

Comment: Is there another way to do it? or can you show me that way?

Comment: I edited your answer. You can see code clicking on `edit` button. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to do this.  You might notice that the integrand is

$$2 \sin{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)} \cos{\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)} = \sin{x} + \sin{y}$$

You may then integrate this over the triangle directly:

$$\frac12 \int_0^1 dx \, \int_0^x dy \, [\sin{x} + \sin{y}] + \frac12 \int_1^2 dx \, \int_0^{2-x} dy \, [\sin{x} + \sin{y}] $$

Note that I formed the integration boundaries from the equations of the lines formed from the vertices of the triangle.  Note also that I had to break this in two: one for the left side and one for the right.

You may then evaluate this in terms of single integrals by integrating over $y$; I get

$$\frac12\int_0^1 dx \, [x \, \sin{x} + 1 - \cos{x}] + \frac12\int_1^2 dx \, [(2-x) \sin{x} + 1-\cos{(2-x)}]$$

I will let you take it from here.

Comment: I think you missed a $\frac{1}{2}$ factor in your first equation and I didn't understand where did the $x\sin x$ appear from?

Comment: @metacompactness: the factor of $1/2$ should show up in an edit - it was a mistake.  The $x \sin{x]$ comes form integrating $\sin{y}$ over $x$.

Comment: Actually, it's integrating $\sin x$ over $y$ but I got your point.

Comment: Where did you get the integral 2sin()cos()?

Comment: @jainsmit: not sure what you mean

Comment: Like you changed it from 2sin(x+y2)cos(x−y2)=sinx+siny

Comment: @jainsmit: that is a standard trig identity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance

1) Solve the system

$$u=\dfrac{x+y}{2},\,v=\dfrac{x-y}{2} $$

for $x$ and $y$.

2) Find the Jacobian

$$ J=\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} \quad \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\  & \\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} \quad  \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix}. $$

3) $$ dxdy = |J|dudv .$$

4) Find the limits of integration for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: so would you just take the integral with J alone?

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin x+\sin y\right)$

The line joining $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ has an equation $y=0$ and $0\leq x\leq 2$

The second line: $y=-x+2$

The third line: $y=x$

The integral becomes:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{x}+\int\limits_{1}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{2-x}\right)(\sin x+\sin y)dy~dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{x}(\sin x+\sin y)dy~dx+\int\limits_{1}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{2-x}(\sin x+\sin y)dy~dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\limits_0^1\left[y\sin x-\cos y\right]_0^xdx+\int\limits_1^2\left[y\sin x-\cos y\right]_0^{2-x}dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left[\sin x-x\cos x+x-\cos x\right]_0^1+\left[(x-2)\cos x-\sin x+x+\sin(2-x)\right]_1^2\right)$$

Comment: why did you make sin and cos into sin+sin?

Comment: @jainsmit It's called [linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_using_Euler%27s_formula) and it is often used in integration.

Comment: ok I got my answer as .545351 is that right?
ans also can you finish the integral so i can compare my work to yours?

Comment: I finished the double integral but I don't have a calculator right now to find the approximate value. You can always use the [Wolfram integrator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%282-x%29*sin%28x%29&random=false) to find the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint we obtain a new coordinate system rotated $\frac{\pi}{4}$ clockwise.
See the following picture.

[image]

A unit area in the new system is the double of the old one.
Thus the integral changes to:
$$2 \int_0^{1} \int_v^1{\sin u \cos v \, \mathrm {d}u \, \mathrm {d}v}$$
which you can easily finish.